Способы имплементации моддинга в C++ проект
Вопрос теоретический: какими путями можно имплементировать в проект на C++ моддинг, не основанный на изменении исходного кода непосредственно?
Очевидным решениям можно считать предоставление некоторого modapi - набора команд и классов для выполнения действий, предусмотренных разработчиком, однако этот метод способен ограничить разработчика мода. Какие еще инструменты можно предоставить?
В C# существует harmony - библиотека, призванная "патчить" исходные функции программы/игры. Возможно ли что-то подобное в C++?

Очевидным решениям можно считать предоставление некоторого modapi - набора команд и классов для выполнения действий, предусмотренных разработчиком. Всё, что разраб захотел отдать мододелам, то он и отдал

В C# существует harmony - библиотека, призванная "патчить" исходные функции программы/игры. Возможно ли что-то подобное в C++? - моды не должны патчить исходные функции. Как вы представляете совместимость модов между собой, если они захотят поменять один и тот же кусок кода, например? Программа должна предоставлять интерфейс подключения внешней библиотеки (мода), функции которой она сама будет вызвать, и у мода должны быть ограниченные возможности. Должен быть не "патчинг" исходных функций, а например переопределение, как при наследовании в ООП.


не именно наследование в смысле C++, но например в игре есть базовый тип NPC, для добавления нового типа мод расширяет исходный тип, описывая что поменялось относительно исходного типа.

